# Backing up a virtual environment, deleting the original, then restoring the backup. Why don't any of the modules work?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I had a virtual environment called `venv` on a raspberry pi. I copied it to my pc via `scp -r rpi@rpiip:~/venv .`, then deleted it from the pi with `sudo rm -r venv`

Then I copied the `venv` folder back to the pi via scp. The folder is exactly the same size as on my PC, so it's definitely the same `venv` folder, however now my scripts don't work. None of the libraries are able to be found!

Is it possible to restore the old `venv` to working condition? Why aren't any of my libraries found after restoring the virtual environment?

EDIT:

Is this behaviour uncharacteristic of virtualenv? Or is it normal for a virtualenv not to be completely self contained like this?

EDIT2:

After activating, the `pip` command returns

```
from pip._internal import main
ImportError: No module named 'pip._internal'
```

Comment: I assume you activated the virtual env again? Is there something preventing just recreating?

Comment: @Tim Yes, I've definitely activated it, I would like to not recreate it as it contains `dlib` and `scipy`, both of which take hours to build on RPi.

I can see all the libraries are there, but pip seems to not work anymore.

Comment: Added update to question

Comment: Is the copy of the venv located at the exact same path as the original venv?

Comment: @jwodder Yep! I copied it to my local pc then copied the exact folder back. When i `ls -l` in the parent directory I can see that the exact same folder exists

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53964819/7976758

Comment: One tip I can suggest to avoid having to recompile `dlib` and `scipy`, you can create your own wheel package specific to your environment using pip. `pip wheel -w /output/path scipy` will generate a precompiled wheel file. You can then just copy the wheel file around and because it is precompiled it will install quickly into a new virtualenv. Note this will need to be done on the RPi as I don't believe cross-compilation is supported.